# Does "The Ravages of Time" manhua have an official Japanese translation?

Tags: the-ravages-of-time

*The Ravages of Time* is a Hong Kong manhua about Three Kingdoms.

Does it have an official Japanese translation? If so, where can I read it?

I googled around and can't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, *The Ravages of Time* has an official Japanese translation, but it only covers the first 9 volumes.**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ravages_of_Time), it was serialized in *Sangokushi Magazine*. According to [the Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E4%B8%89%E5%9B%BD%E5%BF%97%E3%83%9E%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3), it was serialized on the first edition of *Sangokushi Magazine* until it was merged into *Comic Flapper* magazine. For unknown reasons, the serialization ended with only enough chapters for 9 volumes of *tankobon* (the last volume was published on December 2009).

The series is known as 「三国志群雄伝　火鳳燎原」 in Japan and can be bought on:

- [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/bookseries/B00MRTSYN2/ref=dp_st_4840122539) (paperback)
- [ebookjapan (Japanese)](https://ebookjapan.yahoo.co.jp/books/108711/) (e-book)
- and possibly many more